# Access JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm makin an AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "id": id
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

The variable `data` appears in console as:

```
Object {ids: Array[2], values: Array[2], name: "Test"…}
```

Expanding it gives:

```
ids: Array[2]
  0: "1417509840"
  1: "1419964200"
  length: 2
```

I'm unable to access the `ids` array. I can access the `name` variable by `data.name`, but I cannot access the array elements.

Comment: have you tried iterating over them? Or doing something like `data.ids[0]` to get the first index

Answer (score 2):

By the time you see it as `data`, it's not JSON anymore. It's just an object.

To access the `ids` array, use `data.ids`:

```
console.log(data.ids.length); // 2
```

Or loop through them:

```
data.ids.forEach(function(id) {
    console.log("id = " + id);
});
```

*(More about looping through arrays [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), which also explains about polyfilling `forEach` on really old browsers.)*

Comment: I should kill myself. I've been trying it for 1 hour. Actually, there was a typo on server end where I was making the json!

Comment: @u134211: Oh, what fun. :-)